# Sign in with Apple without email id

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, sign-in-with-apple

My application is rejected twice for the “Apple with sign-in“ option. I try to get an email id after the user chooses apple with a sign-in option but in one scenario somehow I don’t get an email id while doing “Sign in with Apple” functionality. I was trying to find ways to reproduce this issue but couldn’t reproduce. Finally today I got to know that in iPhone after creating Apple ID if you go to settings -> Apple ID, you have an option to remove your email id and use the only phone number in place of email id, in this case, I will never get email id while doing “Sign in with Apple”. Unfortunately, my whole application is working based on email id as a primary parameter. In this case, anyone has any idea that how we can handle the uniqueness of the user without changing the architecture of the application?

> So the main issue is If the user is using Apple ID as the mobile
> number I am not able to get the email address of the user or phone
> number

I am stuck in this issue for one week and apple is rejecting my application. Please help me if anyone Is having any idea about it. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: So your users are logging into your app using their Apple ID? Have you considered other options like Face ID?

Comment: my application required to email or phone for registration in my system if my apple id is my phone number so i will not get either phone number or email in sign in with apple

Comment: Just curious, have you considered following Apple's documentation for implementing this service? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/implementing_user_authentication_with_sign_in_with_apple

Comment: Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness
App got rejected :

We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.6.1 on Wi-Fi. Specifically, we receive an error when we attempt to login with Sign In with Apple.
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.6.1 on Wi-Fi. Specifically, we receive an error when we attempt to login with Sign In with Apple.

Comment: @user1374 have you resolved the issue?

Comment: yes, i have added few validation

Comment: @user1374 "few validation" can you explain further?
You should report this to apple. This seems like an apple bug.

Comment: yes, i think so it was, but I managed with validation from our end

Answer (score 0):

You can use the next steps.

If your users use an Apple sign in and you didn't get an email of the user, then you can simply redirect him to the specific additional step where he should add his email for the end of the registration. After that, you will get an email of this user and it will not necessary to change the architecture of the app

Comment: Guideline 2.1 - Performance - App Completeness

App got rejected :
We discovered one or more bugs in your app when reviewed on iPhone running iOS 13.6.1 on Wi-Fi. Specifically, we receive an error when we attempt to login with Sign In with Apple.

Comment: @Alexander Nikolaychuk -  If Touch ID/faceid is validated , we cannot get email from the completion delegate. How to achieve this ? . I need Apple ID (xx@gmail.com is my Apple ID) to check in my system. Please help